# What is the right way use refreshToken?

Tags: android, api, jwt

I am working with an API that needs for some request an access token. The token get refreshed every 10 minutes, so i need to use a refresh token request. The problem is that the refresh token request requires a valid token that didn't expired yet. To summarize my question, is it normal that the refresh token requires unexpired token or there is another safe way to change the logic of refreshing it?

P.S: In the android app usually to refresh token you need get the first failed request than you request an new one and if you you choose to work with WorkManager you'll need at least  15 minutes for the periodicWorkRequest.

Answer (score 0):

In my case this work me as below:

```
        httpClient.authenticator(new Authenticator() {
            @Nullable
            @Override
            public Request authenticate(Route route, Response response) throws IOException {
                String SavedAccessToken = "Bearer "+MyApplication.getLoginUser().getAccessToken();
                String responseHeader   =   response.request().header("Authorization");
                if (!SavedAccessToken.equals(responseHeader))
                    return null;

                // request new key
                String accessToken = null;
                Call<ResponModel<User>> call = RetrofitManager.getRetrofitManager().getApiService().requestAccessToken(MyApplication.getLoginUser());
                try {
                    retrofit2.Response responseCall = call.execute();
                    ResponModel<User> responseRequest = (ResponModel<User>) responseCall.body();
                    if (responseRequest != null) {
                        accessToken = responseRequest.getData().getAccessToken();
                        User user = new User();
                        user.setUsername(PrefsUtils.get("UserName","").toString());
                        user.setAccessToken(accessToken);
                        user.setRefreshToken(responseRequest.getData().getRefreshToken());
                        MyApplication.updateUser(user);

               }
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    Log.d("ERROR", "onResponse: " + ex.toString());
                }

                if (accessToken != null)
                    // retry the failed 401 request with new access token
                    return response.request().newBuilder()
                            .header("Authorization", "Bearer "+ accessToken) // use the new access token
                            .build();
                else
                    return null;
            }
        });
```

Comment: isn't authenticator works whenever you received a failed request? Because i can't do that  I said that the refresh token requires unexpired one